# Deploy Haxe cpp in single .exe

Tags: c++, haxe

I've created an app launcher that basically launches the latest version of an application and I need to deploy it as a single .exe file. It works fine on my computer but when I try it on another computer it seems that it is missing some dependency and I cannot find any documentation on how to deploy haxe cpp and what the dependencies are. My bin folder is full of files like Main.exp, Main.lib but I do not know what they are.

The error I get on the other machines are "Error : Could not load module std@get_cwd__0"

Comment: It seems the other machine is missing the C++ runtime. It needs to install the VS distributable runtime.

Comment: Well, is there a way to include this in the .exe or as a .dll? I have no option to install this on the target machines.

Comment: You could have an installer .exe that installs it, I'm sure.

Comment: Well, the problem is that this launcher will run on all the computers on my company and I have no possibility to install anything, I just need a selfcontained, non-dependent .exe. Maybe I have to build it in .net instead...

Comment: All compilers should have the ability to link all libraries statically. You have to change the settings for your project (if you're using Visual Studio) so it links statically and not uses DLLs.

Comment: I've found out that I needed the std.dll located in the \haxe\lib\hxcpp\3,0,2\bin\Windows, and now it runs fine. Cannot find any way to include it in the .exe though, but this is good enough I belive. Thanks for your ideas! If anybody knows how to compile with static linking in hxcpp, please share!

Comment: Hi @AndreasJeansson, maybe ask on the Haxe mailing list, or OpenFL Google+ group?  HxCPP literally generates ".cpp" files and then compiles them, so static linking is bound to be possible, you just have to find someone who knows how :)